# bundle: Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, bundler

I updated my server to ruby 2.1.1 and I'm using Capistrano for deployment to my server. However when I deploy, I receive various errors. Each time changing as I play with my deploy code. Below is the current issue I have.

## UPDATE/ NEW ISSUE

After reinstalling rvm and ruby I'm now coming across different issues on deploy. Here is my deploy.rb file currently.

```
require "bundler/capistrano"   
require "rvm/capistrano"

set :rvm_type, :system
set :rvm_ruby_string, "ruby-2.1.1"

require 'bundler/capistrano'

# Capistrano
set :default_environment, {
    'PATH' => '/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games',
    'GEM_HOME' => "/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1",
    'GEM_PATH' => "/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1:/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global",
    "MY_RUBY_HOME" => "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1",
    "BUNDLE_PATH" => "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/bundle"

}

set :rails_env, "production"
set :branch,    "master"

set :app_server, "ip"
set :db_server,  "ip"
server app_server, :app, :web
role :db, db_server, :primary => true

set :keep_releases, 1

set :deploy_to, "/var/www"
set :user, :jason
set :password, "cool password here"

set :repository, "git url"  # Your clone URL
set :scm, "git"
set :scm_username, "jason"
set :scm_passphrase, "password"

set :use_sudo, false

default_run_options[:pty] = true

set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}

after 'deploy:restart', 'deploy:cleanup'
after 'deploy:update', 'deploy:create_symlink'
```

When running deploy I come across this error:

```
Error: RVM was unable to use 'default'
```

I assume this refers to `rvm_ruby_string` which I did not set. Beyond that, I have no idea why the error is being produced. Maybe RVM can't recognize ruby on the server?

## OLD ISSUE

I updated my server to ruby 2.1.1. SSHing into the server I run `gem env` grab the relative `default environment` characteristics.

```
set :default_environment, {
    'PATH' => '/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games',
    'GEM_HOME' => "/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1",
    'RUBY_VERSION' => 'ruby 2.1.1',
    'GEM_PATH' => "/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1:/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global"
}
```

However when I run `cap deploy` I get this:

```
  * executing "cd /var/www/releases/20140517014048 && bundle install --gemfile /var/www/releases/20140517014048/Gemfile --path /var/www/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["ip address"]
    ["ip address"] executing command
 ** [out :: ipaddress] sh: 1: bundle: Permission denied
```

I assume its' my default environment. As that is the only thing I changed in my `deploy.rb` file. `

Comment: SSH into the machine, use `which bundle` to find the bundle executable, use `ls -l /path/to/bundle` to examine the file permissions and owner. Look in the `PATH` that you set above for another `bundle` executable too with `find /path/one/ -name bundle` for each path. Try to run the bundle command from the shell. Look at 1st line to see `#!/path/to/ruby`, and use `ls -l` to examine its permissions.

Comment: `which bundle` prints out nothing in the terminal.

Comment: So it said `/usr/bin/which: no bundle in (...`? Set your path to the path above, then run which again.

Comment: No, it returned nothing. Literally nothing. It was as if the command wasn't meant to print anything out.

Comment: What do you get if you type `ls -al /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin` (as root).  Specifically is bundle there and is it executable?

Comment: Odd. I received `ls: cannot access /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin: No such file or directory
`

Comment: Try to uninstall bundle, rvm, ruby, etc., and re-install. Basically you want to make sure everything works from the command line first before using Capistrano.

Comment: It's strange that you use jason user for deployment and evironment paths belong to root.

Comment: I concur. Before the environment paths didn't have `root/` in the file path, but since I reinstalled rvm, ruby, etc. it's now there.

Answer (score 5):

> 1. You'll want to use [`default_env`](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/pull/564) to define the SHELL vars
> 2. `Permission Denied` means your SSH user does not have permission to use SSH, RVM or Bundler

**Capistrano**

The first step is to ensure `default_environment` works correctly. Although I can't find the [direct reference (search for `default_env` on this page)](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/upgrading/), I read that `default_environment` has been superseded by `default_env`

If you're using `capistrano 3.0+`, you should use `default_env` like so:

```
set :default_env, {
    'PATH' => '/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games',
    'GEM_HOME' => "/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1",
    'RUBY_VERSION' => 'ruby 2.1.1',
    'GEM_PATH' => "/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1:/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global"
}
```

---

**Permission**

Secondly, your `ssh` user won't have the correct permissions to access the installation of `Ruby` / `bundler`

As you've discussed in the comments, this can either be caused by `ruby` or `rvm` not being installed on your system, or not having permission to access it.

`@chloe` has an amazing recommendation - to work with that, I would log in using the `root` user (to test), to make sure you can actually access the `bundler` or `rvm` data correctly

Comment: I'm using v2 so default_env is not the issue. I reinstalled rvm, ruby, and bundler. Error went away but I now have a new error that pops up when I run deploy. `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
` Thanks for the help so far though.

Comment: Try installing bundler separately first by using gem install bundle

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Bundler, RVM, Ruby, and re-install them. It worked for me.

Comment: I've done this already. What's your logic with thinking it will work this time around again?